# Stuck in logic for movie guess game in java (by udacity)

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, logic

I am making a movie guessing game(much like hangman but doesn't contain the stick figure and stuff) on Java that takes input from the user, letter by letter. I am stuck where I want the letter entered to replace all instances of that letter in the title of the movie. My code is not working completely. 
Later, I am gonna apply the logic that stops the user from entering the same letter again. But at the moment I need to fix this particular issue. Any help?

This is the game process function in my game class.

```
public void GameProcess(char[] dashedarray) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char guess;
        int i = 0;
        int spaces = 0;
        int correct = 0;
        int wrong = 0;
        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {
            if (dashedarray[i] == ' ') {
                spaces++;
                i++;
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter your guess.");
                guess = input.next().charAt(0);
                for (int j = 0; j < dashedarray.length; j++) {
                    if (dashedarray[j] != ' ') {
                        if (moviename.charAt(i) == guess) {
                            dashedarray[i] = guess;
                            correct++;
                        }
                        else if(moviename.charAt(j) == guess)  {
                            dashedarray[j] = guess;
                            correct++;
                        }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wrong++;
                        }
                    }
                i++;
                PrintArray(dashedarray);

                if (correct == (moviename.length() - spaces)) {
                    System.out.println("You have won.");
                    break;
                } else if (wrong == 10) {
                    System.out.println("You have lost.");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("The number of wrong guesses is " + wrong + ".");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `i` for? why would you check the index at `i`?

Comment: To check the index one by one. j to check the index from zero to end of array inside the i loop for every character.

Comment: what is `moviename` - what is not working?

Comment: Move the whole block `if (dashedarray[i] == ' ')` after the `while` loop out of the loop. Remove everything with `i` and it should work.

Comment: There would be no use of it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `i` at all. `spaces` is to count the number of spaces in your answer, which does not need to be guessed. You should do that outside of the loop.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char guess;
int i = 0;
int spaces = 0;
int correct = 0;
int wrong = 0;
boolean run = true;

for (int i = 0; i < dashedarray.length; i++) {
    spaces++;        
}

while (run) {
    System.out.println("Enter your guess.");
    guess = input.next().charAt(0);

    boolean match = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < dashedarray.length; j++) {
        if (dashedarray[j] != ' ') {
            if(moviename.charAt(j) == guess)  {
                dashedarray[j] = guess;
                correct++;
                match = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // It matched nothing, this input is wrong.
    if (!match) {
        wrong++;
    }

    PrintArray(dashedarray);

    if (correct == (moviename.length() - spaces)) {
        System.out.println("You have won.");
        break;
    } else if (wrong == 10) {
        System.out.println("You have lost.");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("The number of wrong guesses is " + wrong + ".");
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at com.company.Game.GameProcess(Main.java:96)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @MohammadOsamaRajput There is no way we would know where line 18 is.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Game game = new Game();
    String s = game.OpenFile();
    System.out.println(game.GetRnum()+" "+s);
    System.out.println("Turn your Caps Lock on.");
    char[] dashedarray = new char[100];
    dashedarray=game.DashedArray(s);
    game.PrintArray(dashedarray);
    System.out.println("You are allowed 10 wrong guesses.");
    game.GameProcess(dashedarray);
    }

Comment: The last line is line 18.

Comment: `moviename` and `dashedarray` needs to be the same length.

Comment: Okay I fixed that.